# Why does a Foucault pendulum need to swing?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, reference-frames, torque, string

Let's imagine a Foucault pendulum placed at the North pole of the Earth.
If it is oscillating, we know that the plane of the oscillation will stay fixed with respect to distant stars while it would rotate with respect to observers on Earth.

But does it need to swing? Why can't we say paint a spot on the stationary pendulum and see if the pendulum rotates (with respect to us) with the period of 23 h 56 m?

I can think of one answer: When we release the bob at the neutral position, we impart a torque to it because of our own angular momentum so it rotates with the room, no relative rotation detected.
In which case, why does it not work for an oscillating pendulum?

Comment: There are a few things I do not understand in your question: i) what do you mean by "plane of oscillation"? ii) what would be a "stationary pendulum"? iii) what do you mean by "neutral position"? Is it the equilibrium position? iv) which torque are you speaking about?

Comment: i) The plane in which the bob oscillates. ii) A non-swinging pendulum sitting at equilibrium. iii) Yes, the equilibrium position. iv) Let's say you let the pendulum hang at equilibrium, since we are at the pole, Earth should rotate around it and pendulum should remain in place, hence rotating wrt the room; except the pendulum will also rotate with the Earth, and I am proposing it is because we impart angular momentum to it when we let it go.

Comment: Still, something is unclear: a pendulum hanging at equilibrium neither oscillates nor rotates. Moreover, we must hit it to make it oscillate from the equilibrium position. Which angular momentum should we impart to it?

Comment: In the equilibrium position the string of the pendulum is aligned with the rotational axis of the Earth, let us call it +ve Z direction for N direction. If the pendulum rotates with the Earth, it will have angular momentum about the Z direction. It won't be swinging, but it will be turning.

Answer (score 4):

Theoretically, we don’t need the pendulum to swing. Suppose:

- the pendulum is suspended on a joint that can rotate completely frictionless,
- the entire construction is perfectly symmetric,
- the pendulum is an a vacuum,
- the pendulum has no initial rotation with respect to an outside frame of reference (e.g., the galaxy).

In this case, the Earth and the pendulum do not interact anymore (except through gravity).
Thus the Earth’s rotation does not affect the pendulum at all and the pendulum would rotate relative to the Earth.

However, this is not that easy:

- Every support will have some friction.
  Since the forces involved are very small, they would never suffice to overcome the static friction of the support and thus the pendulum would just follow the support and thus the Earth.
  Compare this to slowly turning the legs of a rotating office chair:
  The seat will follow due to the static friction of the axes.

  Now, how does swinging help to overcome this?
  A swinging pendulum can store some of the force by twisting its rope and then unleash it once the force suffices to overcome static friction.
  Here the swinging keeps the rope from immediately untwisting as the momentum and angular momentum of the bob have to be preserved.
  (Of course, using a massive object instead of a pendulum also increases the angular momentum you need to preserve, but at the same time it also increases the frictional forces and rotational inertia.)
- If any orientation of the pendulum has a lower energy than the others, e.g., because the support is slightly tilted and the pendulum is slightly asymmetric, the pendulum will stay there, since the forces are so tiny.
  This is also a difficulty with setting up swinging Foucault pendulums, but again the swinging pendulum can build up force to escape tiny potential wells.
- It is not really easy to prepare an object on Earth such that it is not rotating with respect to an external reference frame (e.g., the galaxy) as opposed to the Earth reference frame – and convince others that you did it.
  (This is more or less the answer you suspected.)
  For example, if we wanted the seat of our office chair to not rotate in the galaxy’s reference frame for a moment, we would need to give it a very tiny push.
  Moreover, it would be very difficult for us and others to check whether we applied the right push.

  One benefit of the Foucault pendulum being a pendulum is that it allows you to do this by construction:
  The pendulum’s motion is mostly linear and hence not rotating with the Earth.

  (Still, when setting up normal Foucault pendulums, this is a challenge:
  You need to avoid giving the pendulum an initial rotational momentum.
  Therefore you cannot just start it by hand.)

Answer (score 0):

If I fully understood your question, using a pendulum at the North Pole, at its equilibrium position, and non-rotating with respect to an inertial reference frame is not a practical substitution for the original Foucault pendulum.

First of all, if it does not swing, it is not a pendulum at all. It is a body suspended so that it can freely rotate around a vertical axis, passing through its center of mass. The same job could be even better done with a permanent magnet levitating over a superconductor. In such a case, a pendulum's specific property is missing, confining each point's motion to keep a fixed distance from the suspension point.

Independently on the issue of the name of such a system, it fails to achieve the primary goal of Foucault's pendulum. I.e., to make evident the non-inertial nature of the reference frame fixed with Earth.
Indeed, whatever the initial rotation of the body, experimenters placed at the North Pole have no way to know whether the body is rotating or not with respect to a non-inertial reference frame by observing its motion.

Therefore, the answer is that Foucault's pendulum must swing if it is used to demonstrate that we do not live in an inertial reference frame.

There is an additional observation I would like to make about the simplified situation of Foucault's pendulum at the North Pole. It is very frequent to read  that "the plane of the oscillation will stay fixed with respect to distant stars while it would rotate with respect to observers on Earth." It is wrong if the sentence is intended to say that the motion is planar in both the inertial and non-inertial reference frames. If the pendulum moves in a plane in the inertial reference frame, its trajectory cannot be an arc of a circle in the rotating reference frame. Indeed, for the typical case of a pendulum starting at rest in the rotating frame, the motion projection on the horizontal plane will look like the figure in an answer to [this related question.](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/576299/how-does-a-foucault-pendulum-work?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

The effect is similar to applying a torque on a rotating object. For example, for a vertical rotating wheel supported by a string only at one side of its axis, the effect of the resulting gravitational torque is the rotating of the plane of rotation. The torque changes its vector angular momentum, and it doesn't fall down as would happen to a non rotating wheel.

The effect of a tiny friction torque on the swinging pendulum (that is rotating all the time, only changing its angular velocity) is to tend to incline the plane of swing, instead of twisting it. So, after some time, instead of straight path, the bob follows a slightly curved one, like a very elongated ellipse. But the end points keep where they were at starting, and as the Earth rotates, they seem to rotate in the room.

The effect of the same tiny torques induced by friction on a stationary pendulum, with zero initial angular momentum, is simply to twist it, resulting that it rotates with the room.